# Scan Line Polygon Fill Edge Table Entry Order

Tags: polygon, scanline

I am trying to figure out the correct order between edges on edge table on scan line polygon fill.

One example here on `Y=1` takes first `AB` line
[image]

And another example takes on `Y=0` `v1v0`.
[image]

I cannot understand why not `AB` instead of `BA` and why `v1v0` instead of `v0v1` respectively

Comment: Why AB instead of BA?  Presumably because the polygon is being defined in anticlockwise order and so all edges are labelled accordingly. In fact, it is important to keep things consistent, especially when creating the edge equations. This is to avoid 'holes' or 'double filling' of pixels when handling "tie-break" cases when the centre of a pixel lies 'exactly' on an edge.